What is effect of updating Process Builder in Managed Package on subscriber org
I am thinking to package a process builder in my managed package (1GP). I have few doubts about it. Can someone please help me with this.

Ones an org installs my package, can it make edits to the process builder, like activating it and also adding additional filters to some filtering logic.
If in future I update the process builder in my org and upload the package again, and then the orgs also update the package versions, what will happen to the process builder updates made by those orgs themselves. Will my updates override them, or their own updates persist only, or some mix-up will take place?
If I don't make any changes to process builder but update something else and upload a new package version, what will happen to the process builder update made by orgs who already have my package and update it. Will they lose their changes, or it will persist.

I am unable to understand how the versioning of process builder itself will take place in such scenarios. I don't want to try this by creating multiple release versions and then deprecating them later on, and beta versions can't be upgraded.
It will help save me a lot of time if someone have priori experience doing such things

In a managed package, your customers cannot modify components. They will be able to activate/deactivate process builders I believe.
In an unmanaged package, your code or components are like open source. Your customers can edit or build upon.
By the way, process builders shouldn’t be used anymore and FLOWS are recommended

Hey thanks for the answer, just two follow ups:

I have just started reading about flows, so if in my question I replace process builder to flows, would the answer remain same, i.e., customers cannot edit the flow from managed package.
I want to have a filtering logic in the process builder/flow to not create a platform event for updates made by a specific user, I cannot put this condition while packaging as the user exists in customer org itself. So is there any way to achieve this?


Your customers cannot edit the flow in a managed package, however you can provide configuration options via custom metadata. Your flow can read from there and execute filter logic

Customers cannot edit a managed package flow, unless the managed package makes it overridable. If the managed package flow is a template or overridable, the subscriber can create a copy then modify the copy. When overridable, any use of the original flow is replaced by the override copy.
